# WCF response: Omit SOAP Structure

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf

I developed a perfectly working .NET WCF web service that produces a SOAP response.

My problem is the SOAP format of the response, cause my final customer is not able to use my web service. (**He expects just the body content of the response**.)

In order to explain better the situation, I have recreated a WCF demo called "Calculator"; a simple web service which performs the Sum of two numbers. (1+1)

When I test the web service on SOAP UI, I have the following response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <s:Header>
      <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
            <u:Created>2015-03-30T14:31:44.759Z</u:Created>
            <u:Expires>2015-03-30T14:36:44.759Z</u:Expires>
         </u:Timestamp>
      </o:Security>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body>
      <SumResponse xmlns="http://MY-PC">
         <SumResult>2</SumResult>
      </SumResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

While, my final customer wants to receive the following response: (**all through a new wsdl**)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SumResponse xmlns="http://MY-PC">
    <SumResult>2</SumResult>
</SumResponse>
```

Is there any way to omit the SOAP format in the response of the WCF web service ? (possibly using .NET standard system libraries)

If there isn't, there is any way to achieve the final result remaining in .NET ?

**Note**: 
I should use the .NET framework 4.0, and the response should have: 
content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' (like SOAP 1.1 format)

Comment: Why create a SOAP service if your client doesn't want SOAP?

Comment: Because I did not know. My delivery consisted in developing a web service, which must be used by consumer's software.
No other information, except for the signature of the service and to create the web service in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the message dispatcher, however i am not sure you would want to do this, If you create an interface your client could easily get the full answer but get back an object with just the values.
Anyway, with the message inspector you can edit the message you are about to send, here is an example:

```
//First you will need to implement 2 interfaces
//IDispatchMessageInspector or IClientMessageInspector and IServiceBehavior or IEndpointBehavior

public class MustUnderstandMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
{

    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel, System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        //Here you can use the ref request(Remember it is a ref, careful what you do with it)
        //request is the message you just received
        SaveInDatabase(request);
        return null;
    }

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        //reply is a ref like request and it is the message you are sending
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

// To be able to implement your MessageInspector in your service you need to create a behavior.
//this behavior will have to be added to your server.

public class UnderstandBehavior : IServiceBehavior
{


    void IServiceBehavior.AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        //This will Add your inspector to every dispatcher inside serviceHostBase
        //you will have to use the one your service is on
        foreach (ChannelDispatcher chDisp in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
        {
            foreach (EndpointDispatcher epDisp in chDisp.Endpoints)
            {
                epDisp.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new MustUnderstandMessageInspector());
            }
        }
    }

    void IServiceBehavior.Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Once you have both interfaces done you will have to add the behavior to your service.

```
{
        svcHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), eventendpoint);
        svcHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), new WSHttpBinding, "Endpoint");
        //Add Service Behavior
        UnderstandBehavior behavior = new UnderstandBehavior();
        svcHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(behavior);
        //////
        svcHost.Open();
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "\n\nService is Running";
        svcHost.Close();
}
```

As shown you can also edit incoming messages you just have to use the message inspector you want.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your time, I appreciate any kind of help.

I don't know if your code could help me, probably I have forgot to specify that the new response must be available through the wsdl of the web service; therefore I hope to resolve by simply updating the service reference in the client software.

Comment: Then the soap specification will be the one to answer that question [SOAPWikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP#SOAP_Building_Blocks). I'm afraid the envelope part is mandatory.